# ubuntu 22.04 process to upgrade GPU from nvidia 2080 super to 4070

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, hardware, gpu

I have a system running with the starting state in the title (ubuntu 22.04 & nvidia 2080 /w the nvidia proprietary '515' drivers. I'm looking to install a new 4070 card.
(currently backing up the drive, so I figured I'd check here)

A straight up card swap results in the nvidia persistence daemon failing to start and refusing to boot the system.

I'm assuming there are steps that I have to take before getting that to work.

My google-fu is failing to turn up anything on this topic. All of my hits come back with how to install the drivers with nothing about the change in hardware complicating things.

My intuition is that I need to revert to the base install graphics drivers.
I have found instructions for completely removing the nvidia drivers - will that cause the system to revert to the default drivers?
Can I just use the "Additional Drivers" tool (gnome) to switch to the xorg nouveau drivers?

Comment: Remove current drivers, change card install the correct drivers.

Comment: Thanks! 
Just finished trying that and it did not work. 
I used the additional driver gnome tool to revert to the nouveau xorg drivers, rebooted successfully, swapped cards & no boot.
At boot I got an endless series of numbers scrolling down in a single column.

Comment: Not what I suggested.